# Laravel adding middleware inside a controller function

Tags: php, laravel

as the title says I want to use a middleware inside a controller function. I have resource controllers, which their functions inside will have different access rights so I can't use a middleware in the web.php file, I have to use or apply it separately in each function to limit access, my googling hasn't been successful in getting a solution to that so far. Any help please and thanks in advance.

P.S. I believe no code is necessary here.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Middleware could also be applied to just one function, just add the method name in your controller constructor

```
public function __construct()
{
    // Middleware only applied to these methods
    $this->middleware('loggedIn', [
        'only' => [
            'update' // Could add bunch of more methods too
        ]
    ]);
}
```

OR

```
public function __construct()
{
    // Middleware only applied to these methods
    $this->middleware('loggedIn')->only([
        'update' // Could add bunch of more methods too
    ]);
}
```

Here's the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#controller-middleware)

Comment: thanks man, that was a huge weight off my shoulders, #notallheroeswearcapes

Comment: Maybe because capes are expensive!

Answer (score 11):

There are **3 ways to use a middleware inside a controller**:

**1) Protect all functions**:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

**2) Protect only some functions**:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth')->only(['functionName1', 'functionName2']);
}
```

**3) Protect all functions except some**:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth')->except(['functionName1', 'functionName2']);
}
```

Here you can find all the documentation about this topic: [Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#controller-middleware)

I hope this can be helpful, regards!

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code inside your controller constructor. The following code will use the *auth* middleware:

```
public function __construct() {
  $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Comment: but this will apply the middleware for the whole controller right?

Comment: Yes, is that a problem?

Comment: that's not a problem but in my case, that's not what I want, a controller has many functions and I don't want the middleware to apply to the whole controller but just for an i.e. update function

Comment: Then just use in within your function, shouldn't be a problem either.

Comment: you mean like this `public function index()
    {
        $this->middleware('loggedIn');
        
        dd('okay');
        return view('account.profile')
            ->withAgents(Agent::all())
            ->withSubscribed(Subscribed::where('email', Auth::user()->email)->get())
            ->withUser(Auth::user());


    }`  it does not work

Answer (score 1):

The very usual way of checking middleware in controller as follows

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('admin')->only([
        'edit' // methods list
    ]);
}
```

but a normal method list can be provided too.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('admin')->only('edit', 'delete');
}
```

If you want to use middleware but do not want to declare it in file structure, you can use closure too along side with **only** chain method

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        if ($condition) {
            return abort(403, 'THIS ACTION IS UNAUTHORIZED');
        }
 
        return $next($request);

    })->only('edit', 'delete');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can simply add middleware at your routes. For example I need to add middleware for my method "registration_fee()" inside "RegisterController", so it will looks like this:

```
Route::get('/pay_register_fee', 'Auth\RegisterController@registration_fee')
->name('pay_register_fee')->middleware(['guest', Register::class, RegistrationFee::class]);
```

"RegistrationFee" is middleware that I want to add.
P.S. Not forget import class or write full path to middleware.